# Selecting specified values

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

This is the table

```
chr
chr1
chr2
chr10
chrU_X
chrM_a_a
```

I want to get only chr%andnumber% (chr1, chr2,chr10 this case) with:

```
select chr
from varianti
where chr like 'chr_'
group by chr
```

But it returns only chr1 , chr2 not chr10.

I want to get the result like this:

```
chr 
chr1
chr2
chr10
```

Is there somethings wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SIMILAR TO:

```
select *
from chr
where col similar to 'chr[0-9]*'
```

or a regular expression:

```
select *
from chr
where col ~ '^chr[0-9]*$'
```

please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2751/3).

Comment: to get a bit more information about `LIKE` and `SIMILAR`in postgres look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html